# Writing a low ^ symbol

Tags: symbols, positioning

Is it possible to to use ^ in the same was as tilde is used in \texttildelow? That is, can a full stop be replaced with the ^ symbol?

Comment: are you looking for `$\land$`  `∧` ?

Comment: Using a suitable font, the Unicode glyph ̭  `U+032D COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT BELOW` could be used: a̭b̭c̭ḓḙfg̭.   g̭̭̭̭̭̭̭̭

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your symbol by lowering a `\^` accent over nothing. Since you seem to want it as a replacement for a period (full stop), you can set the relevant space factor as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\texthatlow}{}{%
  \raisebox{-1.25ex}[0.25ex][0pt]{\^{}}%
  \spacefactor\sfcode`.
}

\begin{document}

Here it ends. And something else.

Here it ends\texthatlow{} And something else.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Uhm, the lowered box has of course a certain depth. If something tall, like a parenthesis, is just below this symbol, this will increase the line spacing. Maybe not too much but for safety I'd smash the depth of the lowered box.

Comment: @campa I agree.

Comment: Can't upvote again, sorry `:-)`

Comment: @campa there is always plan b https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64582761#64582761

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Unicode TeX such as lualatex/xelatex and a suitable font, you may be able to use U+2038 (CARET)  depending on your use case for the symbol. (In most fonts it sits slightly below the baseline, as an insertion marker)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

one two‸ three

\end{document}
```

Comment: (I'm using a system font here as the latin modern and TeX Gyre fonts don't have U+2038)